# How to make title vertical align center with different title length?

Tags: css

[image: Title height issue]

I want to make like below image with vertical align center:
[image]

**How can i achieve it?**

Comment: You should provide some code to show your current solution...

Comment: Share your code...

Comment: Basically, **you can't**. There is NO well-supported CSS mechanism that can equalise heights for elements that do not share a parent. You will need javascript until CSS Grids are better supported.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `display:flex` to your container class like this:

```
.container {
    width: 320px;
    display:flex;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/xpdxyaz6/2/)

Answer (score -1):

First, I would recommend taking time to learn the CSS box model: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html.

This is a fundamental part of CSS and important for your query. For example, the text in the above image is causing the box with the dark grey background to expand. Using the CSS box model you can ensure this does not happen. There are multiple ways to achieve this but one example would be to use a fixed height in px for the element in question.

Vertical aligning of text can be achieved via the `vertical-align` property using a value of `middle`. You can learn more about the `vertical-align` property, and how to use it, on the W3C's site here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

If you need more help please post some code examples of what you're using to create the above.